# Pass a counter to every python logging method

Tags: python, logging

The python logging method can be set to print the time of each event. However if I am running a simulation with its own time variable can that be used in the logger?

The logging Formatter doesn't seem to have an option for that. Can I overload each of the logger functions?

I would like something like:

```
counter = 5
logging.debug("First Event")
counter += 2
logging.warn("Second Event")
```

to produce

```
DEBUG: 5: First Event
WARNING: 7: Second Event
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a [`logging.Filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information):

```
import logging

class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.count = counter
        return True

logging.basicConfig(
    level = logging.DEBUG,
    format = '%(levelname)-8s: %(count)s: %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addFilter(ContextFilter())

counter = 5
logger.debug('First Event')
counter += 2
logger.warning('Second Event')
```

yields

```
DEBUG   : 5: First Event
WARNING : 7: Second Event
```

Comment: OH well that is just a counter, maybe I should have called it something different, what if I wanted the counter to be set externally.

Comment: The ContextFilter can set `record.counter` using globals, just as easily.