# How to create python logger with record number in the log file

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to create a python logger using the logging module.
How can I create a multiple loggers to multiple files that the first character will be a record number?
using formatter I didn't find how to do that

```
formatter=logging.Formatter('%(recored_number)s %(asctime)s %(message)s %(name)s')
```

This is how I wanted the files to be:

First log file:

```
#1 2019-09-05 08:55:10,000 first logger line for log 1 INFO logger
#2 2019-09-05 08:55:20,000 second logger line for log 1 INFO logger
```

Second log file:

```
#1 2019-09-05 08:58:10,000 first logger line for log 2 INFO logger
#2 2019-09-05 08:58:20,000 second logger line for log 2 INFO logger
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar behaviour is achieved in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695181/pass-a-counter-to-every-python-logging-method)

The only difference, is that You have to increment the counter upon processing each log record.

You can add a singleton class `RecordCounter` for this purpose.

```py
import logging

class RecordCounter:
    _instance = None
    _count = 0

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

    def count(self):
        self._count += 1
        return self._count

class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.record_number = RecordCounter().count()
        return True

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(record_number)s %(asctime)s %(message)s %(name)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addFilter(ContextFilter())
```

Comment: Thanks ! this is just what i was looking for

Comment: Thanks for the previous answer, i would like to create multiple log files so that the counter is per log file . how can i count the log records per log file?

Comment: Usually, different logging outputs are handled by `logging.Handler` instances. You can subclass `logging.Handler` to make Your own handler, which will add `record_number` to each record. The singleton is not usable here, then, as You would count the records per instance of handler.
Also, the `Handler` has `filter()` method, just like the `logging.Filter` - so You can easily override it to add `record_number` inside the handler, without the need of using `logging.Filter` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I just found an answer using extra to every log record:

```
formatter=logging.Formatter('%(recored_number)s %(asctime)s %(message)s %(name)s')

log_1_counter=1
log_2_counter=1
log1.info('first logger line for log 1',extra=
{'record_number':str(log_1_counter)})
log_1_counter+=1

log_1_counter=1
log_2_counter=1
log1.info('first logger line for log 1',extra= 
{'record_number':str(log_1_counter)})
log_1_counter+=1
log1.info('second logger line for log 1',extra= 
{'record_number':str(log_1_counter)})
log2.info('first logger line for log 2',extra= 
{'record_number':str(log_2_counter)})
log_2_counter+=2
log2.info('second logger line for log 2',extra= 
{'record_number':str(log_2_counter)})
```

This is provably not the best solution but it works for me